# i want to achieve this circular border design in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: image Link]

I am not able to think logic to achieve this in flutter, so could anybody please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Result**

[image: Result]

Use `CustomPainer` to handle this UI. You can change the property

```
gap:4 ,
borderThinckness:12,
bottomLeftColor: Colors.yellow,
bottomRightColor: Colors.green,
topLeftColor: Colors.purple,
topRightColor: Colors.red,
```

**CustomPainter**

```
double deg2rad(double deg) => deg * math.pi / 180;

double rad2deg(double rad) => rad * 180 / math.pi;

class CircleBorderwith4Color extends CustomPainter {
  final double borderThinckness;
  final double gap;

  final Color bottomRightColor;
  final Color bottomLeftColor;
  final Color topRightColor;
  final Color topLeftColor;

  CircleBorderwith4Color({
    required this.gap,
    required this.borderThinckness,
    required this.bottomLeftColor,
    required this.bottomRightColor,
    required this.topLeftColor,
    required this.topRightColor,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    /// line testing helper
    // Paint herlperPaint = Paint()
    //   ..color = Colors.black
    //   ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.square
    //   ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    //   ..strokeWidth = borderThinckness;

    // canvas.drawLine(Offset(size.height / 2, 0),
    //     Offset(size.height / 2, size.width), herlperPaint);

    // canvas.drawLine(Offset(0, size.height / 2),
    //     Offset(size.height, size.height / 2), herlperPaint);

    Paint paint_TR = Paint()
      ..color = topRightColor
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = borderThinckness;

    Paint paint_BR = Paint()
      ..color = bottomRightColor
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = borderThinckness;

    Paint paint_BL = Paint()
      ..color = bottomLeftColor
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = borderThinckness;

    Paint paint_TL = Paint()
      ..color = topLeftColor
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = borderThinckness;

    ///Bottom Right:: ok
    canvas.drawArc(
        Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: size.width, height: size.height),
        deg2rad(0 + gap),
        deg2rad(90 - (gap * 2)),
        false,
        paint_BR);

    ///BottomLeft :: Ok
    canvas.drawArc(
        Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: size.width, height: size.height),
        deg2rad(90 + gap),
        deg2rad(90 - (gap * 2)),
        false,
        paint_BL);

    // /TopLeft
    canvas.drawArc(
        Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: size.width, height: size.height),
        deg2rad(180 + gap),
        deg2rad(90 - (gap * 2)),
        false,
        paint_TL);

    ///Top Right :: OK
    canvas.drawArc(
        Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: size.width, height: size.height),
        deg2rad(270 + gap),
        deg2rad(90 - (gap * 2)),
        false,
        paint_TR);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**Use Like this**

```
SizedBox(
                width: 400,
                height: 400,
                child: CustomPaint(
                  painter: CircleBorderwith4Color(
                    gap: 2,
                    borderThinckness: 12,
                    bottomLeftColor: Colors.yellow,
                    bottomRightColor: Colors.green,
                    topLeftColor: Colors.purple,
                    topRightColor: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Yea nice Border",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 33),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Or use inside `Stack`.

learn a lot from this question, thank you .

Comment: thank you so much ❤️. i really appreciate your hard work.